# Unable to unlink Testfairy from react-native

Tags: react-native, testfairy

I am trying to unlink Testfairy from my react-native project for production build.To make this happen on a CI server I wrote a script in which one of the steps is to unlink Testfairy--->
`yarn react-native unlink react-native-testfairy`
But whenever I am running this command it fails with the following error-
`rnpm-install ERR! It seems something went wrong while unlinking. Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Any clue what could possibly have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue due to which it was giving error was the presence of duplicate references in `project.pbxproj`. For removing unique references xunique tool can be used.
Post removing the duplicate references the issue should be resolved.
Link:https://github.com/truebit/xUnique

This is also true when unlinking any other native library that you have used in your react-native project.